# IBAction from a UIButton inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ibaction

I created a UITableViewCell in Interface Builder which I have added a UIImageView and a UIButton to.  I have given the UIButton an outlet, and hooked it up to a IBAction with the touch up inside event set.  I assumed it would call this method, as everything looked like it is hooked up:

```
- (IBAction)pressedCheckbox:(id)sender {
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"clicked check");

}
```

Checking the connections tab, I have everything set correctly, the outlet and the action.  And I get no errors, but when previewing the app, clicking on that button inside the UITableViewCell does nothing, and I don't see anything in the logs.

Ideas on why it won't let me click my button which is in a UITableViewCell?

EDIT:

Code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell = topCell;
                break;
            case 1: 
                cell = cell1;
                break;
        }//end switch

    }//end if

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also figured out what the problem was.  I was needing to set different heights for cells and was using:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (indexPath.section == 0) {

          switch (indexPath.row) {

               case 0:

                    return 26;

                    break;

          }//end switch

     }//end if

     return tableView.rowHeight; <-- I just added this and it fixed the issue

}
```

Previously I was only returning a value for cell 0, so it was causing issues with all my other cells

Comment: Don't return "44" - instead return tableView.rowHeight. It is probably 44 but you never know if it might change in some future iOS. Same thing for "26" - get something's frame.size.height if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in IB? It may be worth trying `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents` (in the loadView method of the owning view controller) to see if the problem is the IB link.

Comment: No, using: [cell1Check addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedCheckbox:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that this is a subclass of UITableViewCell right? Are you sure that you are using this instead of the normal UITableViewCell?

Go to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method implementation and look for the line where you instantiate the cell. Make sure it's instantiating it to whatever your subclass is called, and *not* UITableViewCell. If you're confused, post the code for your `codeForRowAtIndexPath` method so we can see it.

Comment: I posted the code.  And no, it is not a subclass, just the normal UITableViewCell.

Comment: Oh okay, so how did you add the UIButton to the cell?

Comment: If you are doing this programatically, you might want to check this out: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15

Comment: I am not doing it programmatically, only because there are quite a few different UI elements in my cell, and I wanted to lay them out in IB.  So, I just created a UITableViewCell in IB, then created an outlet for that, and called that outlet for the cell that I wanted to use it for.

Comment: Look at this link which goes over creating a custom NIB and loading it: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW31

Comment: I figured out the issue. and posted it as an answer.